# Weird freakiness with network rep graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, internet-explorer-8

I'm using Internet Explorer 8, and the rep graph on my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/34022/dforck42?tab=reputation) now looks like this:

[image: weird graph pic]

I just checked and it's not just my graph, other users are showing up like this as well.

Another weird part is that, if I add or remove something that changes the scale of the graph, for a second I can see the normal lines move and then stop behind the fat grey lines.

Comment: Looks fine for me in IE9's IE8 mode.

Comment: Fine for me on the latest Chrome (Windows 7).

Comment: Looks fine on FF8.0 and FF3.6.20

Comment: Reproduced on IE8/Win7. Looks fine on Chrome and FF.

Comment: Ah... repro on IE8 (Win XP)!

Comment: Got funkier when I selected a specific region: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rilhM.png

Comment: Me too. IE8 Windows 7. Started maybe two weeks ago. Looks fine in FF. Has survived through stuff like rebooting the machine and applying updates. Thanks for reporting, @DForck42!

Answer (score 14):

This is caused by an [issue with html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/21) (previously reported in this [highslide dev forum post](http://dev.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=14156&p=61841)). When the shiv is present, the highcharts tracker overlay elements (22px wide) are render fully opaque instead of the  being transparent as intended.

Try viewing this in **IE8**: http://jsfiddle.net/dM3ZR/3/ (funky grey lines).

Then, with the inclusion of html5shiv removed: http://jsfiddle.net/dM3ZR/1/ (all is well again).

---

This problem is resolved if the version from the [innerShiv-branch](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/tree/innershiv) is used (as mentioned in the discussion on the [issue](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/21)). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dM3ZR/2/

<strike>While waiting for the fix to get merged into the trunk, one option is to switch to the older 2.2 version which has been reported to not have this problem.</strike>

**Issue resolved**: [The issue  with html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/21) has been resolved ([c993fe](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/commit/c993fe02582fb1e05ed6cabeaad3160f75fa89a3)), and as [stated by Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120444/134327), the fix has been deployed on SE. We can all expect to see less freaky lines from now on (if you turn a blind eye on freehand circles!). Kudos to the devs at html5shiv and here at SE!

Comment: yup, i get the same results

Comment: Reproduced on IE8/Win7; first link looks funky, second one looks fine.

Comment: Ah ha! Great find.

Comment: Any time line for the fix to html5shiv or a change to the rep graph so that the issue doesn't affect us? I am still seeing the grey lines in IE.

Comment: @Kate As far as I can tell, there hasn't been any updates on this issue from the html5shiv devs or the ones here.  I'm watching the issue on GitHub so I'll keep you posted if I hear anything.

Comment: @kate there's been a flurry of discussion on the issue page. Perhaps we'll see a fix soon. P.s. I haven't had a chance to read through the discussion.

Comment: @KateGregory FYI. This issue is now resolved.

Comment: @ShawnChin I can confirm it looks great now! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As [pointed out by Shawn Chin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117912/144066), the problem is caused by an [html5shiv incompatibility with Highcharts](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/21) in IE8.

We've pulled in a very recent [html5shiv fix](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/commit/c993fe02582fb1e05ed6cabeaad3160f75fa89a3), which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Thanks Emmett. I can confirm that the graphs are now as pretty as ever!